# How to configure a clustered JCache using Ehcache 3

Tags: jcache, ehcache-3

When creating a clustered Cache following the [Ehcache documentation](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.10/clustered-cache.html#clustered-cache-manager), I get a `PersistentCacheManager` implementing `org.ehcache.CacheManager` but not `javax.cache.CacheManager` which is what I need in my Spring 6 application.

On [Ehcache JSR107-Documentation](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.10/107.html) I see no explicit hint regarding clustering.

How do I get a `javax.cache.CacheManager` supporting clustering Capabilities?

This is the example code for configuring clustered cacheManagers linked above:

```
CacheManagerBuilder<PersistentCacheManager> clusteredCacheManagerBuilder =
    CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder() 
        .with(ClusteringServiceConfigurationBuilder.cluster(URI.create("terracotta://localhost/my-application")) 
            .autoCreateOnReconnect(c -> c)); 
PersistentCacheManager cacheManager = clusteredCacheManagerBuilder.build(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is not explicitly mentioned how to configure a clustered JCache CacheManager on [JSR107 documentation](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.10/107.html), but you can find [how to integrate Ehcache-Configuration with JCache Configuration there](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.10/107.html#integrating-configs).

This is my working solution:

```
import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.Caching;
import javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider;
import org.ehcache.clustered.client.config.ClusteringServiceConfiguration;
import org.ehcache.clustered.client.config.builders.ClusteringServiceConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;
import org.ehcache.core.config.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider;

// ...

CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
EhcacheCachingProvider ehcacheProvider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) cachingProvider;

ClusteringServiceConfigurationBuilder clusteringServiceConfigurationBuilder = ClusteringServiceConfigurationBuilder
        .cluster(URI.create("terracotta://localhost/my-application"))
        .autoCreateOnReconnect(server -> server.defaultServerResource("offheap-1"));

ClusteringServiceConfiguration clusteringServiceConfiguration = clusteringServiceConfigurationBuilder.build();

DefaultConfiguration defaultConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration(ehcacheProvider.getDefaultClassLoader(),
        clusteringServiceConfiguration);

cacheManager = ehcacheProvider.getCacheManager(cachingProvider.getDefaultURI(), defaultConfiguration);
```